# Trouble booting read only btrfs snap shots

Tags: btrfs, snapshot

I've set up my system with btrfs subvolumes.  I've got btrfs assistant, snapper and grub-btrfs installed and working.  However my problem is when I try to boot from a past snapshot I fail to load gdm3. I'm sure this has to be caused by the fact that Snapper only creates read-only snapshots.   I've made sure that **/var/tmp /var/cache** and **/var/log** are all writeable by creating separate subvolumes for them and mounting them in my fstab.  On my arch system, this was all I had to do to get a bootable system on read-only snapshots, even though a few services failed.  My snapd is also not happy about being read-only.  Snapd isn't much of a problem as I'm just needing to boot to roll-back my system.  I'd ideally like to be able to boot from a read-only snapshot and be able to roll back my system using btrfs-assistant, which is a gui program.  As of now I can boot from a past snapshot wait for it to get hung up on gdm.service then get in a tty and roll it back by hand.  What else needs to be writeable for gdm to start?